# Switch between home screen to another screen using application

Tags: android, arduino

I'm working on arduino and what i want to do is

There will a button controller connected to my arduino and there will an application installed in my phone and connected via bluetooth. So whenever i do some operation with the button my application will receive the data and based on that data (left/right) i have to switch to the next side (screen) of my phone...

i don't know how to change to next side... if anyone has any idea about this. please share

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use intents to switch to activities on exact button click:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_cool_button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startactivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
             }
         });
```

Comment: Hi vahan, Let me check with this and i will get back to you